# Xamarn forms: How to show a listview under a listview item?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I need to show a list of classes in my UI. Under each class have some options like homework, attendance, etc.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I have implemented the list of classes using the ListView feature. How can I include the options under the listview?

I have created a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hEOiZZk54TpPEK3swYLS_acCmH0oJQK4) with the list of classes. Also I have created a function of options, How can I append the options as a sublist of classist?

**UPDATE**

**My options under each item is same** so I have done like below:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding  AllItems,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander>
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <Label Text="{Binding title}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="Medium" />
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Expander.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label 
                                Text="option1"
                                FontAttributes="Italic">
                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Tapped="LoadOption1"
                                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
                                        </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>

                                <Label 
                                Text="option2"
                                FontAttributes="Italic"/>

                                <Label 
                                Text="option3"
                                FontAttributes="Italic"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Expander.ContentTemplate>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
```

Label gesture function:

```
public async void LoadOption1(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //How can I get the selected class(selected Expander Header) details here
}
```

Comment: You need to enable grouping in ListView. Here is a great example - https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping

Comment: How is the user going to move forward? By clicking on an option under a class or by clicking on the class cell? If it is the first one then you should use grouping. If it is the later then you should add a Bindable StackLayout inside each custom cell which will hold your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Xamarin Forms 4.6, you can look for the Expander https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-4-6/. 
Nota: it is for the moment in experimental mode.

For details about how to set the content of the Expander control, see the following link:

- https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/ExpanderDemos/ExpanderDemos/Views/AdvancedExpanderPage.xaml
- https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/ExpanderDemos/ExpanderDemos/Views/BasicExpanderContentTemplatePage.xaml

Comment: See here :  https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/ExpanderDemos/ExpanderDemos/Views/AdvancedExpanderPage.xaml or this https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/ExpanderDemos/ExpanderDemos/Views/BasicExpanderContentTemplatePage.xaml

Comment: Can you explain the link between the class data and your options? Are the options the same for each class data?

Comment: Please check this for more details: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/410354#Comment_410354

Answer (score 4):

You can create the listview with group style ,and customize the GroupHeaderTemplate , modify the binding data when click on the group , check my sample .

**XAML**

```xml
<ListView x:Name ="lstView" IsGroupingEnabled="true">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding LongName}" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" >
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Comment}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Model**

```cs
public class VeggieModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public bool IsReallyAVeggie { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public VeggieModel ()
    { }
}

public class GroupedVeggieModel : ObservableCollection<VeggieModel> 
{
    public string LongName { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpand { get; set; }
}
```

**Page**

```cs
public partial class GroupedListXaml : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel> grouped { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel> groupedCopy { get; set;  }

    public GroupedListXaml ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        grouped = InitData();
        groupedCopy = InitData();

        lstView.ItemsSource = grouped;
    }

    ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel> InitData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel> grouped = new ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel>();
        GroupedVeggieModel veggieGroup = new GroupedVeggieModel() { LongName = "vegetables", ShortName = "v", IsExpand = true };
        GroupedVeggieModel fruitGroup = new GroupedVeggieModel() { LongName = "fruit", ShortName = "f", IsExpand = true };

        veggieGroup.Add(new VeggieModel() { Name = "celery", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "try ants on a log" });
        veggieGroup.Add(new VeggieModel() { Name = "tomato", IsReallyAVeggie = false, Comment = "pairs well with basil" });
        veggieGroup.Add(new VeggieModel() { Name = "zucchini", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "zucchini bread > bannana bread" });
        veggieGroup.Add(new VeggieModel() { Name = "peas", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "like peas in a pod" });
        fruitGroup.Add(new VeggieModel() { Name = "banana", IsReallyAVeggie = false, Comment = "available in chip form factor" });
        fruitGroup.Add(new VeggieModel() { Name = "strawberry", IsReallyAVeggie = false, Comment = "spring plant" });
        fruitGroup.Add(new VeggieModel() { Name = "cherry", IsReallyAVeggie = false, Comment = "topper for icecream" });
        grouped.Add(veggieGroup);
        grouped.Add(fruitGroup);
        return grouped;
    }

    void Click(GroupedVeggieModel model)
    {
        if (model.IsExpand)
        {
            var index = grouped.IndexOf(model);
            var context = groupedCopy[index];
            foreach (var m in context)
            {
                model.Add(m);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            model.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var label = sender as Label;
        var model = label.BindingContext as GroupedVeggieModel;
        model.IsExpand = !model.IsExpand;

        Click(model);           
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I will try listview grouping and update you. I need to go next page by clicking the inner list, is that possible by this approach?

Comment: I have tried grouped listview, but no data is showing on the UI. Could you please have a look on the new sample? https://drive.google.com/open?id=111RcnIyPhibnMcQH0kCbjVAYuI6UUJco

Comment: My problem is only class data is receiving through service and options data adding from locally. And user moving to next page by clicking the options

Comment: Yes , we can use data from service , but you have to change the model construction , companyList should inherit from List<classOptionsList> , it is object and also list , so that it can be bind on item and group whilst .